# How to restore/undo desktop wallpaper after changing?

Tags: c#

I am creating a screen share application. When screen sharing is started I am changing the desktop wallpaper color to black.

**Problem**
How to restore the previous wallpaper or windows theme?

I am using the code to change the background to solid color, given below

Also, there is an issue with this code, once the background is changed
using this code I am not able to set an image as wallpaper however I
am able to apply themes.

```
public class wallpaperHelper
    {
        public static void SetColor(Color color)
        {

            // Remove the current wallpaper
            NativeMethods.SystemParametersInfo(
                NativeMethods.SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,
                0,
                "",
                NativeMethods.SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | NativeMethods.SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);

            // Set the new desktop solid color for the current session
            int[] elements = { NativeMethods.COLOR_DESKTOP };
            int[] colors = { System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToWin32(color) };
            NativeMethods.SetSysColors(elements.Length, elements, colors);

            // Save value in registry so that it will persist
            RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Control Panel\\Colors", true);
            key.SetValue(@"Background", string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", color.R, color.G, color.B));
        }

        private static class NativeMethods
        {
            public const int COLOR_DESKTOP = 1;
            public const int SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20;
            public const int SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01;
            public const int SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 0x02;

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern bool SetSysColors(int cElements, int[] lpaElements, int[] lpaRgbValues);

            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern int SystemParametersInfo(int uAction, int uParam, string lpvParam, int fuWinIni);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get current WallPaper before change to other:

```
int SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER = 0x73;
int MAX_PATH = 260;
string wallpaper = new string('\0', (int)MAX_PATH);
NativeMethods.SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER, MAX_PATH, wallpaper, 0);

wallpaper = wallpaper.Substring(0, wallpaper.IndexOf('\0'));
```

When restore old wallpaper, just pass it to `SystemParametersInfo`.

```
NativeMethods.SystemParametersInfo(
    NativeMethods.SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,
    0,
    wallpaper,
    NativeMethods.SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | NativeMethods.SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);
```

Aslo, if you don't want change wallpaper permanently, change:

```
NativeMethods.SystemParametersInfo(
    NativeMethods.SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,
    0,
    Newwallpaper,
    NativeMethods.SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | NativeMethods.SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);
```

To:

```
NativeMethods.SystemParametersInfo(
    NativeMethods.SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,
    0,
    Newwallpaper,
    0);
```

This will prevent Window save current change. Your old wallpaper will be restored when you shut down computer and open again. *Very usefull if you change WallPaper to something **sensitive** at midnight and forget restore back :)*

**Note:**

If current wallpaper is a theme you can copy it from:

```
C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\TranscodedWallpaper
```

Save it somewhere. When needed, set wallpaper to this file then delete it.

For '.theme' file, copy

```
C:\Users\<User-Name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\Custom.theme
```

Save it somewhere. When needed, set wallpaper to this file then delete it.

```
rundll32.exe %SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL %SystemRoot%\system32\desk.cpl desk,@Themes /Action:OpenTheme /file:"C:\pathtoYourTheme.theme"
```

If your sure what old theme is, you can pick it back from:

```
C:\Windows\Resources\Themes
```

---

For the set color problem, do you want to get rid of black color behind the wallpaper? One choice is go to `Desktop/Personalize/Desktop background` change `Position` to `Fill`. This option will zoom image to fit screen both horizontal and vertical.

Comment: User current wallpaper is a windows theme `C:\Users\vikas\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\TranscodedWallpaper` When I am trying set theme using your code its not working however if I am setting an image then its working fine

Comment: @VikasBansal that `TranscodedWallpaper` is an image. Windows just rename it. You can copy it to other place, then when needed, pass it to your function then delete.

Comment: @VikasBansal see my edit (at bottom) if it have any help!

Comment: @VikasBansal Thank you! Glad my answer solve your problem.